# How can I change the IP address of my TG585 router?

Tags: router, ip, telnet

On some ISP-customised Thomson TG585v7 routers, there is no way to change the IP address via the GUI. In my case it defaults to `192.168.1.254`.

Is it possible to change it to something else, say `192.168.1.6`?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to change the address via telnet.

You need to connect to the router via telnet:

- `telnet 192.168.1.254`
- enter the usual username and password that you would use to access the GUI

Then enter the following commands:

```
ip ipadd intf=LocalNetwork addr=192.168.1.6/24
ip ipconfig addr=192.168.1.6 preferred=enabled primary=enabled
saveall
```

You may also need/want to disable the DHCP server:

```
dhcp server config state disabled
dhcp server lease flush pool LAN_private
saveall
```

(Note: I'm not sure if the second command is required but it worked in my case)

Comment: This worked for me, but not as expected. I was able to connect to Router Page via a custom IP 192.168.1.2 but at the same time 192.168.1.254 was also working. In addition after a router restart custom IP wasn't working.